# convert categorical features to numeric features using One hot encoding,

Tags: python-3.x

## convert categorical features to numeric features  using One hot encoding

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('bank.csv',index_col=0)
X = dataset.iloc[:,:].values
Z = pd.DataFrame(X)
print(Z)

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder,OneHotEncoder
labelencoder_X = LabelEncoder()
X[:,0] = labelencoder_X.fit_transform(X[:,0])
Z = pd.DataFrame(X)
print(Z)
```

but for columns, it can only can be convert 1 single column. how can i conver tmore columns, like columns 1,2,3 and more together.
i was tried to change '0' to '0:', but then it comes with error that " ValueError: bad input shape (11162, 16)."
and if i change X[:,0] to X[:,1,2,3...],then it comes with erroe that "IndexError: too many indices for array"

Answer (score 0):

I have a function that can do the job for you:

```
# Own implementation of One Hot Encoding - Data Transformation
def convert_to_binary(df, column_to_convert):
    categories = list(df[column_to_convert].drop_duplicates())

    for category in categories:
        cat_name = str(category).replace(" ", "_").replace("(", "").replace(")", "").replace("/", "_").replace("-", "").lower()
        col_name = column_to_convert[:5] + '_' + cat_name[:10]
        df[col_name] = 0
        df.loc[(df[column_to_convert] == category), col_name] = 1

    return df

# One Hot Encoding
print("One Hot Encoding categorical data...")
columns_to_convert = [col1,col2]#Enter your column names here that you want to one hot encode.

for column in df_all.columns:              #columns_to_convert
    if df_all.column.dtype == 'category':
        df_all = convert_to_binary(df=df_all, column_to_convert=column)
        df_all.drop(column, axis=1, inplace=True)
print("One Hot Encoding categorical data...completed")
```

Make sure you enter your list of columns (if you dont want all categorical variables to be converted) in the columns_to_convert.